# XPath Variable In SimpleXML With Multiple Values In Predecate

Tags: php, xml, variables, xpath, simplexml

I am working with XML that has a node titled `<SCOPE>`.
If the Scope is equal to "teaching," the code follows one path;
if the Scope is not equal to "teaching," the code follows another path.
I would like to also check to see if Scope is equal to either.
Is this possible in using a variable?
Here is my code (below).  However, this returns no results, whereas using the separate values (either "Teaching" or "Scholarship/Research" return values).

```
$strXpathVar = "Teaching|Scholarship/Research";

$xml_awards_honor_scope_all = $xml_award_honor[0]->xpath('a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="'.$strXpathVar.'"]');
```

Comment: `'a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="Teaching" or a:SCOPE="Scholarship/Research"]'`

Answer (score 2):

The `|` allows to combine multiple Xpath expressions. So this is possible.

```
$scopes = ["Teaching", "Scholarship/Research"];

$xml_awards_honor_scope_all = $xml_award_honor[0]->xpath(
  'a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="'.$scopes[0].'"]|a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="'.$scopes[1].'"]'
);
```

However the conditions support operators like `or`. Most of the time a better solutition would be like this:

```
$scopes = ["Teaching", "Scholarship/Research"];

$xml_awards_honor_scope_all = $xml_award_honor[0]->xpath(
  'a:AWARDHONOR[a:SCOPE="'.$scopes[0].'" or a:SCOPE="'.$scopes[1].'"]'
);
```

Comment: If you don't know how many terms will be in the $scopes array, would it be possible to write a condition that checked each term in the $scopes array?

Comment: In other words, would it be possible to write a condition that would compare SCOPE one time to all elements in the array?

Comment: Generate the expression in a loop (it is a string), make sure that the words do not include a quote char.

Comment: Would I somehow generate the entire expression earlier in the script, or plug in the string into this expression?

Comment: You build the expression up as a variable using string operators and functions. Then you use the variable.